# Jquery smooth scroll external anchor link

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

okay can you please help me with a peice of jquery code. Here is what i want to happen. My website is cyberfanatic.com right so. So for example lets just use the footer for now. i have a a tag with the id of footer right. so say if someone visits cyberfanatic.com/#footer right now the page will load and the then jump directly to the bottom of the page to where the anchor link with footer is. How can i get it so that when the page cyberfanatic.com#footer loads that the page loads and the smooth scrolls to the anchor with the id of footer. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `scrollTo()` [plugin](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/) function

```
$.scrollTo("#footerid");
```

Comment: however i want this to work for all hash's not just footer. Please give me the whole code because the code you provided above i do not know what to do with it.